# Exponents of the Coxeter group A(n)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I came across the following result : "**The exponents of the Coxeter group A(n) (n>=1) are 1, 2, ... , n.**" I am not able to figure out a proof of this fact. **Any help towards proving this result will be greatly appreciated!** Actually, this result has an important application in finding out the dimension of isotonic cones in the isotonic regression problem.

Comment: What are the Coxeter groups of type A(n)? Since notations are not as standard as one might wish, it will surely be a good idea if you are more specific about what groups you have in mind.

Comment: Following the notation [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coxeter_group), it would seem that $A(n) \cong S_{n+1}$.

Comment: The Coxeter group A(n) is defined as the finite reflection group, whose Coxeter graph has only the edges joining the following pair of vertices: (1,2) , (2,3) , ... (n-1,n). Put in another way, each element and the product of any two non-consecutive elements of the generator are involutary, and the product of any two consecutive elements of the generator is nilpotent of index 3. The corresponding Coxeter graph is just a straight line through the points 1,2,...,n.

Comment: @SomabhaMukherjee now what do you mean by the exponent of the group?  Do you mean the definition given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_group)? If so, then you're statement about the exponents appears to be incorrect.

Comment: @SomabhaMukherjee, please add any information to the question itself, which you can edit. In any case, in your explanation you use the word nilpotent, but that cannot be correct. Also, your use of the word ezponents is correct, but is likely to confuse people: you can help others by being explicit about the fact that you mean the degrees if fundamental invariants (people are going to understand that you mean exponents of the group in the *other* sense)

Comment: No. The exponents of the group A(n) are just the negative roots of the polynomial of degree n+1, with coefficients |H(k)|, where H(k) denotes the number of maps in the finite reflection group with dimension of 1-eigenspace = k.

Comment: In any case, the computation of exponents can be found in most textbooks on the subject; the one by Bjorner and Brenti probably doés this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $W = S_{n + 1}$ one Coxeter element is the $n$-cycle $(1 \ 2 \ \cdots \ n + 1)$ so the Coxeter number is $h = n + 1$.  Now the following definition is not the one you've stated in the comments, but it's the definition that I know and it makes the computation for $S_{n + 1}$ easy so if you can prove that yours is equivalent then you'll be set:

**Definition:** Let $\xi \in \mathbb C$ be a primitive $h^\text{th}$ root of unity.  The *exponents* of $W$ are the integers $0 < m \leq h$ such that $\xi^m$ is an eigenvalue of a Coxeter element of $W$ in it's representation on the root space $V$.

Now in type $A_n$ we get $S_{n + 1} \subseteq \mathrm{GL}_{n + 1}(\mathbb R)$ as permutation matrices and the root space $V$ is the set of vectors orthogonal to $v_0 = \sum_ie_i$.  The minimal polynomial of an $(n + 1)$-cycle permutation is $x^{n + 1} - 1$ so any $(n + 1)^\text{th}$ root of unity is an eigenvalue.  But we have to ignore $v_0$ because it's not in the root space.  As $v_0$ spans the $1$-eigenspace of an $(n + 1)$-cycle this means the minimal polynomial is $\frac{x^{n + 1} - 1}{x - 1}$ and so the eigenvalues are exactly the $(n + 1)^\text{th}$ roots of unity except for $1$, i.e., they are $\xi^m$ for $m = 1, 2, \ldots, n$.